# 2012-2015 Horror movie with crawling creatures

Tags: story-identification, movie

So back in about 2012-2013 I watched this movie and I was hoping someone could help me find a title for it.

All I can remember that happened in it is a family just moved into a new house. A wife, husband and daughter. The husband was the main character and also a doctor. But anyway the people of the town they moved to acted strange towards them. And these creepy, crawling things were stalking them. But one of the things got pregnant and kidnapped the father to conceive the baby.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: Typically, conceiving happens before pregnancy. Do you mean birthing the baby? Were these crawling creatures human-size? Smaller? Larger?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean [Deep in the Darkness](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2994948/) (2014). The women of the town hold the secret that keeps a truce with these mutated creatures.

> A doctor and his family move to a quiet, small town. Soon he discovers the town's dark secret: A terrifying race of controlling creatures that live in the darkness in the forest behind their home.

Comment: From Wikipedia: _"Lady Zellis pays Michael a visit. She cryptically tells him that “they” will be coming for him so that he may deliver a child and if he were not needed, he would already be dead because he did not complete the sacrifice. **Michael's home office is then invaded by feral Isolates, who drag him to their underground caverns where he is forced to deliver the child of a pregnant savage.**"_ Seems like a match! Good catch!